# External sd card reader issue. Quite suspicious

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, lubuntu, sd-card

I have a multi card reader. When I plug it in nothing happens. OK its empty... I open the Disks app on my computer (Lubuntu 15.10). It recognizes it well. (it shows Generic USB CF reader - no media, Generic USB SM reader - no media, etc. ..., Generic USB SD reader - no media).

Next I insert the SD card (SDHC to be exact) and it shows Generic USB SD reader : Size 2,2 TB (its real size is 16GB!!!) and unknown partitions. I tried to make a new partition table using gParted but I keep getting input/output error. Here's the output of fdisk:

```
jan@jan-lubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
[sudo] heslo pro jan: 
fdisk: /dev/sdb nelze otevřít: Chyba vstupu/výstupu // translated: /dev/sdb could not be opened:input/output error
jan@jan-lubuntu:~$ 
jan@jan-lubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.26.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.
fdisk: /dev/sdb nelze otevřít: Chyba vstupu/výstupu // again the same error message!
jan@jan-lubuntu:~$
```

My only idea is that the reader is not suitable to read SDHC SD cards.

If you need something just ask and tell me how to obtain it.

Comment: What partition table and  file system is there on the SD card? Maybe you can check it in a computer with Windows. - There might be a partition table or file system, that does not work with linux. Maybe you can install some special drivers for it.

Comment: It is supposed to have partition table from raspbian wheezy image from last year. I'll check it out using windows computer but I have no idea where to find what kind of partition table it has.

Comment: Perhaps what drivers could help me? So I can try them out?

Comment: The partitions for raspbian wheezy should definitely be readable by Ubuntu (and other linux distros). Something else is wrong. Maybe the SD card is worn out (damaged physically), maybe 'only' the partition table is damaged. You can try in another computer and with another card reader. - Are there important files on the drive, that you want to recover? In that case you can try with PhotoRec, https://www.cgsecurity.org/